# can someone help me fix this code to once per day ip?

Tags: php, sql

I am working on a voting system with personal vote links.
I want to make the personal vote page to register IP and make sure the IP can only vote once per day per person( creator ).
The vote page looks like this:

http://forum.thestronghold.nl/vote4creators.php

Can someone help me fix the vote link page? For now it looks like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `DB3121646`.`vote4creator` SET `Votes` = Votes +1 WHERE `vote4creator`.`id` = 6;";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo " Creator : " . $row["Creator"]. " "." Votes : ".$row["Votes"]."<br>";

    }
} else {
    echo "";
}

$conn->close();
?>
<?php
/* Redirect browser */
header("Location: http://forum.thestronghold.nl/vote4creators.php");

/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We will be glad to help you if you get stuck on a *specific* programming problem, but we are not here to write code or design your system for you. You will need to at least make an attempt at solving your own issue. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Issues: I get my IP from a DHCP server, my IP lease renews every hour and I get a new IP, does that mean I get to vote 24 times a day?  Issue2: My buddies and I all sit behind a NAT, so we all appear to be coming from the same IP, does that mean only one of us gets to vote?

Answer (score 0):

**what you have to do is** (simple, but not ideal solution):

1. generate $uid = uniqueid(); per voter
2. add uid to voters cookie with expiry date calculated to today's midnight+ 1sec
3. on every new vote system have to check visitors if cookie exists (!exists = new visitor and/or not voted today)

**additional you can:**

4. add this uid to database with her/his ip ( eid (int unsigned) | voter_ip varchar(16) | voter_uid varchar(32) will do the job done)
5. and check cookie aginst database (select count() where voter_ip = $_SERVER['remote_host'] and voter_uid = $_COOKIE['vote_hash']) - *(it's pseudocode, so validation is needed)*
6. if (rows == 0) { not voted } *(if you wish to give them two votes per day just check if (rows <2) )*

i hope it will guilde you to solve your problem.

*btw: uncle google if full of examples how to do that in many ways ;)*

Comment: setting cookie will overcome both issues : it checks your browser not your ip, so both ip change and nat users can vote, but : 1. in another browser you can still vote 2dn time and 2. you can always delete cookie to make next vote ;P 
if this is (still) a problem, then ideal option for you is to create user account and then save if user voted in your pool :)

Comment: is it possible you show me how to implement this ? im kinda just starting with php/sql so im pretty much a scrub so far XD and uncle google gives so many options i dont know where to start to be honest..

Comment: as @alex-howansky mentioned in his comment : _we are not here to write code or design your system for you. You will need to at least make an attempt at solving your own issue._
howewer just do what i wroted in pts. 1-3 of my answer. you don't need sql. also your work should start from those functions and topics in php docs:
`setcookie
$_COOKIE/superglobals`
all you need is to take database update in one if - just check cookie and update if absent, then set. else don`t let vote.
i can help you for about £50/$70 ;)

Comment: @WesleySlayerKaneMelissen did you managed? was my answer helpful?